# Node.js + express how to add string to the request body?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, proxy

I have a reverse proxy that works fine:

```
app.post('/geoserver', function (req, res) {
    apiProxy.web(req, res, {target: serverOne});
});
```

The request has already a body as following:

[image]

I need to add to the request body a string similar to this one:

```
'<Filter> .... </Filter>'
```

Before proxying to the `serverOne`.

Tried with `req.body = req.body.replace('</Query>','<Filter> .... </Filter></Query>')` but body seems to be undefined.

Any idea on how to solve this? Big thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **I found no solution**, finally created a .Net handler that easily allows to modify the body content.

Accepting as solution for closing the question.

Answer (score 1):

Look, anything can be changed into string by String conversion. but here in this case you can use JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(*)), * can be any format for which you want to change the format, here JSON.parse() will format your text and JSON.stringify() will help you to make valid JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the body might be `undefined` if the request is failing, or incorrectly parsed.

Try `app.use(express.bodyParser())`. It's better to use it on the whole app.

Sometimes, when express is failing, you might want to use [connect.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect)

If you are using it, there might be some place for reverse engineering, and checking if the most simple request is reaching, since the screenshot you've provided is from the dev tools, right? That means it might be only sent, but not received/incorrectly interpreted.

Comment: req.body is undefined :/

Comment: Oh wait, your req.body is undefined?

Comment: Yes it is! Don't understand why

Comment: Okay, thats a very significant part of the question, you better update it to `body is undefined` instead of just `it is not working`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: No worries, all good. Just be sure to include all the possible info :)

Comment: Body parser is not working because the request content-type is not application/json. The body is an xml so it is not possible to json parse it

Comment: Okay, are you using something for that? 
express-xml-bodyparser might be a good way of parsing it, otherwise you can do it by hand.